# How often do CAPTCHAs appear?

Tags: support, questions, captcha

Really just looking for honest answers from fellow users for this one.

How often do you get CAPTCHAs, and what were you doing when it appeared?

Some future scripts I'm working on may attempt actions that could at times require a CAPTCHA, which would throw a big wrench into the gears. I'm just trying to figure out when I can expect to see them, and when I can expect to avoid them.

I myself have only had to answer a CAPTCHA once, and it was on my first post ever.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To trigger CAPTCHA while editing, asking, or answering:

- The minimum window is 5 seconds
- The maximum window is 40 minutes

There is a maximum of:

- one edit every 30 seconds
- one answer every 60 seconds
- one question every 60 seconds

To trigger CAPTCHA while doing performing other actions, there are throttles of various sizes depending on the action -- it's mostly a "slow down" speed bump to inhibit potentially dangerous "I'm going to post obscene things as fast as possible!" situations.

Some new reductions in CAPTCHA throttle thresholds, **if you have > 10k rep**:

- for edits -- reduced by two-thirds
- for post submission times -- min seconds reduced by one half, max minutes increased by x2

Assuming you are a logged in user and have >= 200 reputation: after successfully completing one captcha, we now suppress captcha for 5 minutes on your account.

The maximum window for submitting a post or edit [has been removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38008/eliminate-the-captcha-on-long-questions-answers/38232#38232).