# Captcha on our own post

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, captcha

Would it be possible to disable Captcha when a user is editing is own question/answer ?
At least for something like 15m after the post (to prevent mass change on someone posts if account is hacked).

Comment: Just to make it clear - you're saying that you'd want the captcha restoring after the 15 minutes? Sound's about right to me.

Comment: Yes, no captcha when editing my own post that was posted less than 15m ago.

Comment: I've seen the Captcha 2 or 3 times and it doesn't really bother me. Seems like changing the rules is a waste of time. See also http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/are-you-a-human-being/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why we should be any more or less concerned about "own post" (I can't see a reason to distinguish this from any other editing). The current captcha rates are [discussed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1343/how-often-do-captchas-appear).

Most edits (with some exceptions such as edits immediately after posting) can be rolled back / undeleted / etc - so if something bad happens, don't panic...

Answer (score -1):

I do a lot of writing, and a lot of editing, and the captcha has never annoyed me. If anything, I like seeing it...wondering what odd combination of words I might get. Got a great one the other day, so I sent it in to Jeff and Joel for the blog. I find the good in it. It's keeping the site clean, and adding a bit of mystery to your interactions ;)

Comment: I'm actually scared at just how upbeat that is. I mean, the captcha doesn't annoy me as such, but... ;-p

Comment: Come on, Marc. Have some koolaid ;)