# What triggers the CAPTCHA page?

Tags: support, captcha

Occasionally, when I ask a question on some Stack Exchange site, I'll see a page [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/captcha) wanting to verify whether or not I'm human.

I'm trying to figure out what I am doing that looks suspiciously non-human. How is this page triggered?

(Ironically, when I posted this question, it asked me to do the CAPTCHA.)

Comment: Good try, robot.

Comment: I'm *pretty sure* that this won't get an (official) answer. Documenting what makes the system suspicious would make it far too easy to game the system.

Comment: I agreed with @Joachim, until I found [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1343/how-often-do-captchas-appear). Its a couple of years old, but will give you an idea of how it works.

Comment: What triggers the CAPTCHA for me every time is if I paste a question or answer into the edit box and then hit "Post" straight away.

Comment: @JoachimSauer If documenting their security measures would make them easy to game, then they have poor security measures, i.e. *security through obscurity*.

Comment: I strongly believe in Kerckhoff's Principle, but there's a difference between making something secure and making it harder for spam bots to waste everybody's time.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, that page tends to appear when I write my answer in Notepad, for example, then paste the answer into the answer box and then immediately click Post Your Answer.

Comment: +1 Just because your name is Peter O., like me.