# Why am I getting so many captchas?

Tags: support, captcha

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How often do captchas appear?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1343/how-often-do-captchas-appear)

I've not had to solve a captcha on SO for ages, now suddenly every second click I have to solve another one. has something changed?

Comment: I had to solve 3 captchas just to post this question

Comment: That begs the question: are you human?

Comment: The one time I have had CAPTCHAs for *every single time* I post, I made a mistake with a userscript I had written which essentially broke SO's JavaScript. Now it's unlikely the exact same thing happened to you, but please see if there's anything wrong with SO's JavaScript on your browser

Comment: @Bart, well I'm certainly not a script!

Comment: @Yi, I'm not running any userscript. Maybe my browser has cached some broken js from SO

Comment: Pro tip: Don't have your bot run on the same account as the human, give it *another* account.

Comment: @gnibbler - "well I'm certainly not a script!" ... _That's precisely what a script would say_!

Comment: ***Nice try, robot!***