# Why am I prompted for a CAPTCHA even though I didn't trip any of the rate limits?

Tags: support, captcha

Why am I prompted for a CAPTCHA when posting even though I didn't trip any of the rate limits for CAPTCHAs documented in [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)?

Comment: Because we're on to your kind, robot.

Comment: Damn, busted again!

Comment: You're probably associated with a sketchy IP (proxy?) that has been know previously to produce spam... or something like that. When I used to used proxies, Google would hit me with captchas occasionally when I tried to do a search. Are you on University wifi by chance?

Comment: Nah, tethered to my phone.

Comment: did you take too long? Happens to me sometimes. I mean, checking to see I'm human? That's speciesist.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Maximum times were removed a long time ago.

Comment: Pretty sure I got hit by it semi recently, when I wandered off halfway while writing an answer, and wandered back to finish it off.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog thanks for saving my question.

Comment: I have been able to replicate this behaviour when posting answers that contain a single letter, despite not tripping any of those rate limits. Perhaps the anti-spam system thinks your post looks a little too spammy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the comments, you are tethering your phone.

It is likely that your phone's data provider is doing [carrier-grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT), which makes you share your IP address with a lot of other users at once, and makes you look less like a "real person."  There is (probably) nothing you can do about this other than changing to a different carrier or using a different internet connection.

However, [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2293/275243) suggests that CAPTCHAs can also be triggered by trying to do things too often or too quickly, as a form of rate-limiting.  If that's the case for you, then you may be able to improve the situation by slowing down.