# Posting a draft should not lead to a captcha

Tags: feature-request, captcha, draft

Sometimes, I write a question which I do not immediately post (for various reasons), but choose to save it as a draft instead. When I open the 'Ask Question' page again, and click the 'Post Your Question' button too soon, I first have to [solve a captcha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2293/295232) before I can submit the question.

I understand the need for some rate limiting here, but when I spent a few minutes writing a draft, that should be taken into account. Drafts are only saved after [45 seconds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238/295232) so they should not be tripping the 'post within 5 seconds after opening the page' captcha.

<sub>(I'm not sure if answer drafts exhibit the same behaviour, but this feature request would apply to answers as well.)</sub>

Comment: Why would a user with 74.8k rep ever have to solve a captcha to post? I think the SE network should recognize you are not a bot by now!

Comment: Somebody could hack my account and use it to post multiple questions in a very short time. Rate limits do make sense, but not always. Oh, and about me not being a bot: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46593872 & https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11540?m=50113452